# How do I get openssh to save my ssh identity permanently in Xfce?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, xfce

How do I change it to save my identity permanently using Xfce? During my login session after I have entered:

```
$ ssh-add
```

Then identity is saved and I can connect via ssh without getting the dreaded:

```
Enter passphrase for key
```

However, once I logout and login back-in I get the following when running:

```
$ ssh-add -L

The agent has no identities.

$ ssh <hostname>

Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Stackoverflow has the following solution, yet I do not understand the reference to in the config file:

`IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_buhlServer`

Specifically I do not understand what I would put on the identity file.  Would I put the above word for word?

Or just add my file:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

[StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/add-private-key-permanently-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu)

Comment: `ssh` is completely independent of your window manager. Are you using the same login for Xfce and Unity?

Comment: I have a brand new clean install of Xfce and ubuntu.  I wiped out the old unity install.  I have a Ubuntu server and do not have this problem and neither on my other Ubuntu clients.  Something must be different.

Comment: I took Xfce out of the question and just focused on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm thinking that Xfce/Gnome may actually make a difference. Which desktop environment are you having issues with?

Comment: Also, note that Xfce and Gnome are not just window managers, they're actually desktop environments, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_Window_System_desktop_environments

Comment: Thanks for that. I have added Xfce back to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Xfce may well be the cause of your problem. Gnome, which underlies Unity, provides the [GnomeKeyring](https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring), which can automatically unlock SSH keys for you—it *replaces* `ssh-agent`, as far as I can tell, and it supports `ssh-add`. You can interact with it using Seahorse. In your Unity install, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `seahorse`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run Seahorse. Then look for a key labelled "Unlock password for: " and your key name. If you find one, that's probably what is causing the automatic unlock on Unity/Gnome. In that case, to get the same effect on XFCE, you might try [these instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME_Keyring#Use_Without_GNOME) from [ArchLinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) on using Gnome Keyring without Gnome. (I have no idea if they actually work; I just found them and I've found Arch's explanations helpful in the past.)

**Further Reading:**

- https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring/Ssh
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seahorse_%28software%29
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent#Many_implementations
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys#GNOME_Keyring

Comment: Your guidance put me on the right track. Once I understood  that it needed the **GnomeKeyring** I found that all was needed in **Ubuntu-XFce** was to goto _Settings-Session and Startup-Advanced_ and select **Launch GNOME services on startup** and it saved the identity to the keyring.

Comment: I could have also installed the key manager for Open SSH [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-debian-linux-server-install-keychain-apt-get-command/) as this article seems to point out.  I have since then installed it on my Ubuntu Server and the key stays even when I logout.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `keychain` (the key manager for OpenSSH) in your comment above. I'd never seen that before, but it looks handy. I figured I'd provide a link to the source here (which includes the docs in the readme) in case others are interested: https://github.com/funtoo/keychain